# Tox: different test sets during local and gitlab CI runs

Tags: gitlab, pytest, tox

A subset of pytest tests cannot run on gitlab due to dependencies on locally ran services.
How can I exclude them from gitlab CI pipelines while keeping them for local testing? I am not sure if the filtering needs to be done in pytest, tox or gitlab config.

Current configuration:

```
tox.ini

[testenv]
commands = pytest {posargs}
```

```
gitlab-ci.yml


build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - tox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way of doing that is dynamically through pytest

```
def test_function():
    if not valid_config():
        pytest.xfail("unsupported configuration")
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use two different `tox.ini` files.

While `tox` looks for a `tox.ini` by default, you can also pass in a separate `tox.ini` file like...

```
tox -c tox-ci.ini
```